# Select all columns where column name starts with string

Tags: python, python-polars

Given the following dataframe, is there some way to select only columns starting with a given prefix? I know I could do e.g. `pl.col(column) for column in df.columns if column.startswith("prefix_")`, but I'm wondering if I can do it as part of a single expression.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {"prefix_a": [1, 2, 3], "prefix_b": [1, 2, 3], "some_column": [3, 2, 1]}
)
df.select(pl.all().<column_name_starts_with>("prefix_"))
```

Would this be possible to do lazily?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting from ***Polars 0.18.1*** you can use `Selectors`([`polars.selectors.starts_with`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/selectors.html#polars.selectors.starts_with)) which provides [*more intuitive selection of columns from `DataFrame` or `LazyFrame` objects based on their name, dtype or other properties*](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/selectors.html#selectors).

```
>>> import polars as pl
>>> import polars.selectors as cs
>>> 
>>> df = pl.DataFrame(
...     {"prefix_a": [1, 2, 3], "prefix_b": [1, 2, 3], "some_column": [3, 2, 1]} 
... )
>>> df
shape: (3, 3)
┌──────────┬──────────┬─────────────┐
│ prefix_a ┆ prefix_b ┆ some_column │
│ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---         │
│ i64      ┆ i64      ┆ i64         │
╞══════════╪══════════╪═════════════╡
│ 1        ┆ 1        ┆ 3           │
│ 2        ┆ 2        ┆ 2           │
│ 3        ┆ 3        ┆ 1           │
└──────────┴──────────┴─────────────┘
>>> # print(df.lazy().select(cs.starts_with("prefix_")).collect()) # for LazyFrame
>>> print(df.select(cs.starts_with("prefix_"))) # For DataFrame
shape: (3, 2)
┌──────────┬──────────┐
│ prefix_a ┆ prefix_b │
│ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ i64      ┆ i64      │
╞══════════╪══════════╡
│ 1        ┆ 1        │
│ 2        ┆ 2        │
│ 3        ┆ 3        │
└──────────┴──────────┘
```

Answer (score 8):

From the documentation for [`polars.col`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.col.html), the expression can take one of the following arguments:

> - a single column by name
> - all columns by using a wildcard “*”
> - column by regular expression if the regex starts with ^ and ends with $

So in this case, we can use a regex expression to select for the prefix.  And this does work in lazy mode.

```py
(
    df
    .lazy()
    .select(pl.col('^prefix_.*$'))
    .collect()
)
```

```
>>> (
...     df
...     .lazy()
...     .select(pl.col('^prefix_.*$'))
...     .collect()
... 
... )
shape: (3, 2)
┌──────────┬──────────┐
│ prefix_a ┆ prefix_b │
│ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ i64      ┆ i64      │
╞══════════╪══════════╡
│ 1        ┆ 1        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2        ┆ 2        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3        ┆ 3        │
└──────────┴──────────┘
```

Note: we can also use [`polars.exclude`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.exclude.html) with regex expressions:

```py
(
    df
    .lazy()
    .select(pl.exclude('^prefix_.*$'))
    .collect()
)
```

```
shape: (3, 1)
┌─────────────┐
│ some_column │
│ ---         │
│ i64         │
╞═════════════╡
│ 3           │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2           │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1           │
└─────────────┘
```